# Passing props to router, using redux and react-router

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I'm trying to set up the router in my app using redux and stateless components.

Here I have my **routes.jsx** file:

```
const TodoApp = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {props.children}
            <Footer />
        </div>
    )
};

export default (
    <Route  component={TodoApp}>
        <Route path='/' component={TodoList} />
    </Route>
);
```

First of all, `props.children` is not working. I don't know what's wrong in there.

Of course, I have my **AppRoot.jsx**:

```
export default (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
            {routes}
        </Router>
    </Provider>
)
```

where *{routes}* are the routes above.
What I'm actually trying to do here is to have a kind of template where the footer (and navbar, or whatever) is always there, and then I change the `props.children` with whatever is on the route (TodoList in this example.)

Comment: The error doesn't look to be in the code you posted. Can you describe the behavior you observe? What do you mean `props.children` is not working? Are you sure the `<TodoApp>` component is being rendered, as well as both nested `<Route>` components? Put some quick `console.log` calls and see what's getting called and what isn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to export component *function* instead of *instance* in **routes.jsx**

```
export default () => (
    <Route component={TodoApp}>
        <Route path='/' component={TodoList} />
    </Route>
);
```

and **AppRoot.jsx**:

```
export default () => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
            {routes}
        </Router>
    </Provider>
);
```

For complete examples take a look here: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux

Comment: not working. now i'm getting "Uncaught Invariant Violation: ReactDOM.render(): Invalid component element. Instead of passing a component class, make sure to instantiate it by passing it to React.createElement."

Comment: could you please provide a code where you are rendering Root into the DOM?
try to modify it to smth like this: ReactDOM.render(<Root store={store} history={history} />, document.getElementById('root'))